# What is the purpose of net_device.uc_promisc field?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

why `struct net_device` has a field `uc_promisc`? How this field is used?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a device that doesn't support unicast filtering has to listen to several unicast addresses, it is put on promiscous mode, according to `dev->uc_count` and `dev->uc_promisc`. Check the `__dev_set_rx_mode()` function.

Many devices implement `ndo_set_rx_mode()`, and set their unicast (and multicast) filters via `ndo_set_rx_mode()`. For devices that don't implement that, Linux sets the device to promiscuous mode, and keeps track of that fact with `dev->uc_promisc`.

So there are several flags for promiscuous mode:

- `dev->flags & IFF_PROMISC` means the device is in promiscuous mode.
- `dev->gflags & IFF_PROMISC` means the user has requested promiscuous mode.
- `dev->uc_promisc` means promiscuous mode has been enabled (actually, its reference count has been incremented) due to the need to listen to additional unicast address in a device that doesn't implement `ndo_set_rx_mode()`.

Comment: Thanks ninjalj for the reply. So, if `uc_promisc` field is not 0, does it mean that interface also listen on all addresses in `dev->uc` list?If yes the flag `IFF_PROMISC` should be set? I have a master device with a slave device associated and in `open` method of slave dev i've a call to `dev_uc_add` for the master. This puts master in promisc mode but the flags `IFF_PROMISC` is not set because `ndo_change_rx_flags` is `NULL`. Do you think that this could be correct?

Comment: @MirkoBanchi: if the device supports `ndo_set_rx_mode()` it uses that and doesn't touch `dev->uc_promisc`. If `uc_promisc != 0`, then the device is in promiscuous mode, to be able to listen to all addresses in `dev->uc`. When a device is in promiscuous mode, `dev->flags & IFF_PROMISC` is true, but userspace only sees `dev->gflags & IFF_PROMISC`, so don't trust userspace. The flag is set whether or not `ndo_change_rx_flags()` sees it, `ndo_change_rx_flags()` doesn't change the flag, it informs the device of the flag.

Comment: Drivers may not implement `ndo_change_rx_flags()`, and see changes to `IFF_PROMISC` and `IFF_ALLMULTI` via `ndo_set_rx_mode()` (e.g: e1000) `ndo_change_rx_flags()` is a newer addition, to avoid race conditions (see http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commit;h=24023451c8df726692e2f52288a20870d13b501f)

Comment: Also, the _netdev_ mailing list (http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#netdev) may be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a way of enabling (or tracking the enabled/disabled status of) [promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) on the device.

Comment: There is a specific flag for that: IFF_PROMISC. You can check if the interface is in promisc mode by an ioctl call with command SIOCGIFFLAGS...I can't figure out the reason for the existance of that field...